# How can i give a color to a blank row that is above a specific text?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to give a color to the entire row that is blank but only if above a specific text. The specific text is on column A. Struggling to find a code that i can use /modify, can you please help?

```
Sub Reformat()

    Dim SrchRng3 As Range
    Dim c3 As Range, f As String

    Set SrchRng3 = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("B:B").End(xlUp))
    Set c3 = SrchRng3.Find("Customer account", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c3 Is Nothing Then
        f = c3.Address
        Do
            With Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A" & c3.Row & ":Q" & c3.Row)
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 53
            End With
            Set c3 = SrchRng3.FindNext(c3)
        Loop While c3.Address <> f
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would be good if you could acknowledged the answer to your previous question. Why is your code searching column B?

Comment: ^ Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already pretty close, try this adjusted code:

```
Sub Reformat()

Dim SrchRng3 As Range, ws As Worksheet
Dim c3 As Range, f As String
Dim colorRange As Range

Set ws = Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")
Set SrchRng3 = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Set c3 = SrchRng3.Find("Customer account", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c3 Is Nothing Then
    f = c3.Address
    Do
        Set colorRange = ws.Range("A" & c3.Row - 1 & ":Q" & c3.Row - 1)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(colorRange) = 0 Then colorRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 53
        Set c3 = SrchRng3.FindNext(c3)
    Loop While c3.Address <> f
 End If

End Sub
```

In your original code you were looking for your specified string in column `B`, not column `A`.